# Numerically stable evaluation of $x^{n!}$

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, exponentiation

Given that $x$ is a real number with property $0 < x < 1$ and $n$ upto $4000$
Is there a good way to decompose the n! into steps for multiplying x?

Comment: The result will be effectively zero for most $n\ge9$

Comment: Effectively zero is such an application specific term.

Comment: @PeterForeman you are right. 4000 is the worst case, but I should at least calculate the powers also for 3999... as long as they aren't effectively zero. Btw. x will be very close to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Minimal number of multiplications in worst case $n=4000$: $N_{\min}=\lceil\log_2 4000!\rceil=42\,100$. “Bruteforce” approach, using fast multiplication for power 2, then 3, then 4 etc gives $N_{bf}=\sum_{k=2}^{4000} \lceil\log_2k\rceil=43\,905$. So it's less than 5% inoptimal. I wouldn't be bothered with writing a sophisticated algorithm.